# Dockerfile установка дополнительных пакетов

Tags: dockerfile

Здравствуйте хочу создать образ Ubuntu 2204 чтобы в нем содержались следующие инструменты, make g++ valgrind
мой Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt update
RUN  apt install make
RUN apt install valgrind
RUN apt install g++
COPY . /project
WORKDIR /project
```

Получаю ошибку:
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt install g++]: exit code: 1

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y check
RUN apt-get install -y make
RUN apt-get install -y valgrind
RUN apt-get install -y g++
COPY . /project
WORKDIR /project
```

так все работает как надо

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь давать более развёрнутые ответы, ответ на вопрос должен быть **исчерпывающим**. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Ответ можно отредактировать кнопкой «[править](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1520414/edit)».